# ExtJS ActionColumn - layout text fixed to left and icon fixed to right edge in cell in Grid

Tags: extjs

I'm using ActionColumn to display an icon inside cells in columns in my Grid.

I'm trying to set the layout so that the text is always fixed about 5 px from the left edge of the column and the icon is always fixed about 5 px from the right edge regardless of the length of the text which is dynamic in each row.

I'm using "iconCls" with a background image to show the icon, I'm not using "icon"

I can display both the text and icon aligned on the left, or, both text and icon aligned on the right but have not found a way to align the text on left and the icon on the right.

```
var column = {
                xtype:'actioncolumn',
                text : grpName,
                selItem:selGrps[i],
                dataIndex : 'g_' + grpId,
                groupId : selGrps[i].get("id"),
                height : me.self.HEADER_HEIGHT,
                sortable : false,
                items: [{
                    iconCls:'dropArrowIconCSS',
                    handler: me.actionColumnHandler
                }]
        }
```

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code? And what version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: Hi,  I added code.  Using ExtJS 4   Thanks for any thoughts